# Smooth image of an open set is open

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to prove that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a smooth map such that $\mathrm{det}(d_{x}f) \neq 0$ for all $x \in U$, then $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

My reasoning so far is as follows:

> Let $y \in f(U)$. We want to show that $B(y; \delta_{y}) \subset f(U)$; that is, there exists some $\delta_{y} > 0$ such that the ball around $y$ of radius $\delta$ is contained within $f(U)$. Since $y \in f(U)$, there exists some $x \in U$ such that $y = f(x)$. Since $U$ is open, there exists some $\delta_{x} > 0$ such that $B(x; \delta_{x}) \subset U$. It follows that $f(B(x, \delta_{x})) \subset f(U)$, which is some neighbourhood around $f(x) = y$.
>
> Since $\mathrm{det}(d_{x}f) \neq 0$, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $d_{x}f$ so that $(d_{x}f)(v) \neq 0$ for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $v \neq 0$. We can express each point in $B(x; \delta_{x})$ as $x + h$, where $h \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is some displacement from $x$ and, necessarily, $|h| \leq \delta_{x}$. Consider the set of points $x + v \in B(x; \delta_{x})$ where $|v| = \delta_{x}/2$. Now we have that
>   $$
> f(x + v) = f(x) + (d_{x}f)(v) + \text{ some small error},
> $$
>   so $y + (d_{x}f)(v) \in f(B(x; \delta_{x}))$. Let $\delta_{y} = \min_{v}\{|(d_{x}f)(v)|\}$ so that $B(y; \delta_{y}) \subset f(B(x; \delta_{x})) \subset f(U)$ as required. Since $y \in f(U)$ was arbitrary, $f(U)$ is open.

Informally I am trying to say that, since $\mathrm{det}(d_{x}f) \neq 0$, no displacement vector from $x$ collapses to $0$ around $y$ which means that the points around $y$ are the images of some points around $x$, but I'm not sure how to write that formally.

Comment: Have you learned about the inverse function theorem?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Not formally, but I thought that would require extra conditions that I don't have?

Comment: If by smooth the text mean $C^1$ then you may apply it.

Comment: Surely this is part of the proof of the inverse function theorem? (meaning that it can't be applied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last formal part (the fact that the map is an open map) may be viewed as a corollary to the IFT unless you are in the process of proving it, as mentioned by Littlewood in the comments. But the statement is not really the IFT.

Given $y\in f(U)$ you have  $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in U$. Then $d_xf$ invertible and $f\in C^1$  enables you to apply the IFT:  Thus, there exists neighborhoods $V\subset U$ of $x$ and $W\subset {\Bbb R}^n$ of $y$, and a $C^1$ map $g: W\rightarrow V$ so that $f:V\rightarrow W$ and $g:W\rightarrow V$ are bijections and inverses of each other. But then $W=f(V)\subset f(U)$ is an open neighborhood of $y$ in $f(U)$ as wanted.